# I want to use sumproduct on two different tables based on 3rd Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm a Boy Scout Assistant Scout Master and was asked to help with a fundraiser so I'm trying to put together a Excel sheet.  I would like to use sumproduct to pull together the totals I need from two tables. My result would be in B3 in referenced pic.

Math:
(C7 * B18) + (C14 * B19)
or
(.19672 * 300)+(1 * 200)
Result of 259.02

```
Need
 Table 2 Dist Hours
 Table 3 Total
From
Table 1 Name = $A$3
Table 1 Name = Table 2 Name
Table 2 ID = Table 3 ID
```

I hope someone can help our Boy Scout Troop (me)

[image]

Comment: You have the formula if you put an `=` sign in front of it. Might help to explain why that is not working or is not sufficient so we know what the issue is.

Comment: I'm unsure how to build the sumproduct formula to do what I'm looking for.  Close as have managed is pulling data from table 2.  What I'm describing is the issue in the math to get to my answering.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, not just ENTER...

```
=SUM(IF(B7:B14=A3,SUMIF(A18:A19,A7:A14,B18:B19)*(C7:C14)))
```

Adjust the ranges accordingly.

Comment: thank you this is great! I will set up with dynamic named ranges and use this combination of formulas :).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For a finite (and static) number of entries in table 3 this method of stacking error controlled lookups should produce the correct result for any name put into table 1.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C7:C14, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$8)/((A7:A14=A18)*(B7:B14=A3)), 1))*B18, 0)+
 IFERROR(INDEX(C7:C14, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$8)/((A7:A14=A19)*(B7:B14=A3)), 1))*B19, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This is close :).  I'm trying to not have to know exact locations of anything other than the table itself. I could do a vlookup to it and do as described.  But truth is table 3 is my primary data table for the entire sale where as I'm getting % allocation by name from Table 2.

Comment: I would be summing up 15 - 20 fields from table 3 and adding to table 1.  Both table 2 and 3 will be dynamic in size.  Table 1 is fixed by scouts.